# Combine multiple instances of jquery code

Tags: jquery, instances

I am currently using the below to toggle multiple div's but am wondering if i can combine all of these into one?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tvehicle").click(function() {
        $("#div7").toggle();
    });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tvehicle2").click(function() {
        $("#vehicle2").toggle();
    });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tproperty").click(function() {
        $("#div8").toggle();
    });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#thproperty1").click(function() {
        $("#hproperty1").toggle();
    });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#thproperty2").click(function() {
        $("#hproperty2").toggle();
    });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#thproperty3").click(function() {
        $("#hproperty3").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: @Legs could you post up your HTML structure please?

Comment: @DavidBarker the HTML has a lot of senstive work stuff in but i will strip that out and replace it with something else and post it when i get a chance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#tvehicle").click(function(){
  $("#div7").toggle();
 });

$("#tvehicle2").click(function(){
 $("#vehicle2").toggle();
});

//AND SO ON...

});
</script>
```

You can put all functions in one single document.ready function. Like above :)... Also you dont have to have new `<script>` tags for every function.

Comment: You can remove alot more still legs, this is a good answer but you should make some other changes to your HTML structure as well to reduce it much much further.

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to all the divs, e.g.:

```
<div id="tvehicle2" class="toggleable"> ... </div>
```

then you can do:

```
$(".toggleable").click(function () {
    $(this).toggle();
});
```

if you don't want (or can't) add a class to all the toggleable items, you can also combine multiple id-references in a selector:

```
$('#tvehicle1, #tvehicle2, #tv3').click(function () {
    $(this).toggle();
});
```

Comment: In the above example how would i specify what div each id-reference is to toggle?

Comment: It will toggle the one you clicked on -- which is bound to `this` inside the event handler (and only that one).

Comment: sorry, I see what your problem is.. the toggled items aren't the same as the ones being clicked.  Do they have any dom-relationship, e.g. is one contained in/next to the other?

Comment: They all toggle the div directly below them however some are contained in different div's

Comment: If directly below means the same as next, you could use `$(this).next().toggle()`, however the better solution is to use data-* attributes like @Yury explained in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use data attributes to specify which element to toggle.
[example](http://jsfiddle.net/9tEF7/6/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var toggler = function() {
   var toToggle = $(this).data().toggleId; //Id of an element to toggle

   $("#" + toToggle).toggle();        
};

$(".togglers").on("click", ".toggler", toggler);
});
```

HTML structure

```
<div class="togglers">
<div class="toggler" data-toggle-id="to-toggle-1">Click to toggle 1</div>

<div class="to-toggle" id="to-toggle-1">I will be toggled #1</div>

<div class="toggler" data-toggle-id="to-toggle-2">Click to toggle 2</div>

<div class="to-toggle" id="to-toggle-2">I will be toggled #2</div>

<div class="toggler" data-toggle-id="to-toggle-3">Click to toggle 3</div>

<div class="to-toggle" id="to-toggle-3">I will be toggled #3</div>
</div>​
```

​

Comment: You should include the substantial bits of code from the fiddle in your answer.

Comment: Data attributes: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/  .. and in jQuery http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: 175 lines have become 9! Thank you so much!